# Flutter InAppWebview pass custom event data to the handler function

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I want to pass the arguments which are coming in a custom event to the flutter handler function.

I tried this in `onPageLoaded`

```
Future<void> onPageLoaded(InAppWebViewController controller, Uri? url) async {
await controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            window.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', (event) => { 
              window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('myHandlerName');
            }, false);
          """);
    controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
      handlerName: 'myHandlerName',
      callback: (args) {
        //I want to get the args here but it is always an empty list
      },
}
```

dispatching a custom event from web like below:

```
const event = new CustomEvent("myCustomEvent", {
    detail: {foo: 1, bar: false}
});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I want to get the args that are passing from the custom event in my handler function but it is always an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way how to pass the data:

I must pass the `event.detail` to my handler function in order to get the args in my handler's callback.

```
window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('myHandlerName', event.detail);
            }, false);
```

Now I can see the args which I am passing:

controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
handlerName: 'myHandlerName',
callback: (args) {
// List which contains the custom event data now
},
);